# Searching movie by title, sql vs http access

Tags: imdbpy

My doubt is, when I make a movie search by title in a another different language than English, why the search is more precise if use HTTP access than SQL ?

For example i want to retrieve info about the Movie "El gran Robo" (spanish title) original title "Flypaper".

case 1) using SQL access

```
ia = IMDb(accessSystem='sql', uri = "mysql://devel:password@localhost/imdb")
movies = ia.search_movie("el gran robo")
for m in movies:
  print m['titles']
```

OUTPUT:

- 7 uomini e un cervello
- El gran rabo
- List item
- Mathias Sandorf
- La gran revista
- Green River
- Green River
- The Grim Reaper
- The Grim Reaper
- La commare secca
- Anthropophagus
- La verte moisson
- Granny R.I.P.
- Gehirnreflexe
- Rosso sangue
- Green River Killer
- Grammar Revolution
- German Whorefare 4
- Cuori in campo
- Grim Reaper
- Grim Reaping

case 2) using HTTP access

```
ia = IMDb()
movies = ia.search_movie("el gran robo")
for m in movies:
  print m['titles']
```

OUTPUT:

- Flypaper
- The Big Steal
- Robbery
- El gran robo del tren
- El gran robo de Lorenza
- The Bank Job
- The First Great Train Robbery
- Grand Theft Auto
- The Great Train Robbery
- Hot Money
- 7 uomini e un cervello
- The Great Missouri Raid
- Le Great Dane Robbery
- El gran río
- Después del gran robo
- Gran-Robo tonda

As you can see, the search with HTTP returned the right Movie, Flypaper.

Is it possible get the same results using SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: some data are missing in the plain text data files.

Extended explanation in the imdbpy-help mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/p/imdbpy/mailman/message/33067664/